I have created 3D view from images using Nerfstudio NVIDIA successfully, now I want to download the output for using on my ecommerce platform
I have created 3D view from 2D images successfully and it's working well, now I need to get it as output for using on my ecommerce platform
these are the commands I used to build it
git clone --recursive https://github.com/nvlabs/instant-ngp
open developer cmd
cmake . -B build
cmake --build build --config RelWithDebInfo -j 16
conda create -n ngp python=3.11.5
pip install -r requirements.txt
pip install openexr-3.2.4-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl
python scripts/colmap2nerf.py --colmap_matcher exhaustive --run_colmap --aabb_scale 16 --images data/playground
C:\ngp\instant-ngp\testbed.exe --scene data/D31

I want the result as output,
simply saying I want to run that output on any device or website without the help from nerfstudio
